# Maintain ASP.Net membership passwords during machine key change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there an utility or code sample that can decrypt with the old key, and then encrypt passwords with a new key for ASP.Net membership users?

Answer (score 2):

None of the workarounds mentioned worked for me. 
My solution is below. It involves first storing passwords in clear text and then reencrypting them again with new MachineKey.

[Machine Key Change](http://artisticcheese.blogspot.com/2014/04/changing-machinekey-on-iis-while-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess at a solution, but I haven't had a chance to test it.  It relies on the following settings for your current provider:

```
enablePasswordRetrieval="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted"
```

It also assumes that the new machinekey is already in the config file.

Create the following class (thanks to mootinator for the jumpstart on this)

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MySqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        protected override byte[] DecryptPassword(byte[] encodedPassword)
        {
            MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");
            section.DecryptionKey = "oldkey"; // TODO: Set your old key here

            MethodInfo method = typeof(MachineKeySection).GetMethod("EncryptOrDecryptData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            return (byte[])method.Invoke(section, new object[] { encodedPassword, null, 0, encodedPassword.Length, 0, false, false });
        }
    }
}
```

In your web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="TODO" passwordFormat="Encrypted" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="TODO" passwordFormat="Encrypted" type="MyNamespace.MySqlMembershipProvider"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Change the passwords with the following code:

```
MembershipProvider retrievePasswordProvider = Membership.Providers["MySqlMembershipProvider"];

foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
    MembershipUser retrievePassworedUser = retrievePasswordProvider.GetUser(user.UserName, false);
    string password = retrievePassworedUser.GetPassword(); // get password using old key

    user.ChangePassword(password, password); // change password to same password using new key
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Nice, if that works it avoids writing to an intermediate location which is what I ultimately did.  I'll test it out.

Comment: section.DecryptionKey = "oldkey"; is readonly and cannot be set.. unless there's a way to override it I ended up retrieving / decrypting first saving to file then changing the key and updating passwords.

Comment: Looks promising, but `typeof(MachineKeySection).GetMethod()` is returning null.

Comment: You might need to add a MachineKey section to your config.  I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by setting the key on the fly:

You might have to extend the `SqlMembershipProvider` (or whatever you use) to get access to the `protected DecryptPassword` method.

```
    MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");

section.DecryptionKey = "old";
// Read old password
section.DecryptionKey = "new";
// Store new password
```