# Unable to find EncryptOrDecryptData

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, membership

I have to change the MachineKey of an application that is running aspnet Membership, so as far as I know I'm going to have to update all the passwords of the users.  I'm trying to do this programmatically and found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091110/maintain-asp-net-membership-passwords-during-machine-key-change)

when running the following code

```
method = typeof(MachineKeySection).GetMethod("EncryptOrDecryptData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

byte[] stuff = (byte[])method.Invoke(section, new object[] { encodedPassword, null, 0, encodedPassword.Length, 0, false, false });
```

method is null.

Also in that code I am unable to modify the MachineKeySection, but I feel like I can work around that.

Comment: How are your passwords stored - Hashed, Encrypted or Clear Text?

Comment: The passwords are encrypted.  I was wondering if I was missing a reference or something.  I ended up working around the problem but I still wonder why I could never find this method?  Its in all of the documentation.  I am using .Net Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can change "BindingFlags.Instance" to "BindingFlags.Static" and try it. Because "EncryptOrDecryptData" is an internal static method in the class of MachineKeySection.